# AutocompleteInput with ReferenceInput not clearing underlying state on erase

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm trying to set a ReferenceInput with an Autocomplete input and I'm getting a bit of a weird behaviour that I'm not sure if it's intended or not. If I confirm the autocomplete option on the field, and then erase the field for any reason, the id value is still associated with the field, even bypassing a validate={required}.

```
<ReferenceInput allowEmpty source="postId" label="Post" reference="posts">
                <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" optionValue="id" options={{maxSearchResults: 5, filter: AutoComplete.fuzzyFilter}} />
</ReferenceInput>
```

Any idea on how to fix it in order for the autocomplete to work properly and yet erasing it also clearing the underlying field?

Comment: That's an issue. I'll see what we can do

Comment: Thank you @gildas . For the moment we switched to using a SelectInput, so for those struggling it can be an easy way out, at least while we don't have many records.